# Djcelery : How to save celery task status into database

Tags: python, django, celery

My celery task runs well
But I found my `djcelery_taskstate` table has nothing   :
[image]

How can it save data into it??

Here is my setting :

`settings.py`

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'  
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Taipei'
```

`celery.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
from django.conf import settings  # noqa
app = Celery('myproject')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Taipei'
)
```

`tasks.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from celery import task
from datetime import timedelta
from myapp.deal import check_data


@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=30),name="collect-rawdata",ignore_result=True)
def rawdata():
    return check_data()
```

Here is my command to run celery  :

one  terminal run:

```
celery -A wiarea worker -l info
```

another run:

```
celery -A wiarea beat -l info
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set [`ignore_result`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.ignore_result) to True. This makes Celery drop the result and not save it anywhere.